# Correlation between multiple response variables in a LMM framework?

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis

I am often asked to analyze data from agricultural experiments with some form of blocked design (typically randomized complete block). I use general(ized) linear mixed models with appropriate random intercepts, sometimes random slopes, by block. Often there is more than one response variable (for example yield, disease score, leaf tissue chemistry, etc.). I usually fit a separate (G)LMM for each response variable.

However the researchers are often interested, for descriptive purposes, in knowing the **correlations between pairs of response variables**. Typically I just take the Pearson correlation between the pairs of variables, ignoring the blocking structure of the experiment. This seems like it could result in an inflated correlation coefficient because there are multiple data points from the same block that aren't independent of one another. But I don't know a good way of accounting for this structure without fitting some kind of complex multivariate linear mixed model. This seems excessive for descriptive statistics, but I also feel like it's wrong to report inflated correlation coefficients.

Can anyone point me to a good solution for this problem, or any existing resources on the topic? R code would also be helpful.

*edit*: I guess a possible solution would be to fit an intercept-only model with the appropriate error structure for variable 1, and do the same for variable 2, then take the correlation of the residuals from each of the two models. Would that correctly account for the non-independence of values from  the same block, in the context of the pairwise correlation?

Comment: One option you could consider is a multi-level SEM, which provides a multi-level framework but also the freedom of multiple outcomes. But that is fairly complicated and I'm not sure if thats what you are after.

Comment: Yes I agree that multilevel SEM would be amazing! But as you note, it is sort of a lot to do for a descriptive statistic that is being included as an "afterthought." It may be best to just report the raw correlation coefficients with the caveat that they are based on partially non-independent data points and thus are only a rough indication.